# Responsa/Rabbinic Thought on Israeli Reprisal Operations

Tags: army-military-war, state-of-israel, responsa, morality

During the 1950s and 60s, the IDF [carried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reprisal_operations_(Israel)) out what have become known as "reprisal operations" against Arab villages. Some of the operations, especially Operation Kibya, were condemned on the world stage.

My question is this: did the reprisal operations as a whole, or any specific operations, receive Rabbinic treatment? In other words, are there any responsa discussing the permissibility of these operations? And if there aren't formal responsa, were there vocal Rabbis in support or against the operations as a whole? Given the moral quandaries the operations raised, I wonder if they drew the ire or approval of Rabbinic authority.

Comment: similar: Yabia Omer 11 CM22

Comment: Can't seem to get my hands on a Yabia Omer. Can you perhaps summarize @Dr.Shmuel with what is written there and how it pertains

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Rabbi Shaul Yisraeli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaul_Yisraeli) wrote a lengthy essay on the subject shortly after Qibiya, published in his book עמוד הימיני, pp. 113-139. He first noted:

> "מאז נסתיימה המלחמה ה"רשמית" של מדינות ערב בישראל ע"י שביתת הנשק, לא פסקו מקרי הסתננות של כנופיות ערביות לשם מעשי גנבות ושוד מזוין...בחשון תשי"ד ביצעו הכנופיות הפושעות מעשה רצח ברוטלי של משפחה שלימה בכפר יהוד. נראה הי' הדבר שהכנופיות פועלות בצורה מאורגנת בעידוד ובתמיכה של האוכלוסיא הערבית במקומות הסמוכים לגבול...היישוב שנפגע החליט כי אסור לשבת הלאה בחיבוק ידים עד שיבואו ח"ו קרבנות נוספים. ובאחד הלילות התקיף בצורה תקיפה את היישוב הערבי קיביה, שידים מוכיחות שהכנופיות הרצחניות באו משם וקיבלו את תמיכת האוכלוסיא...העולם "הגדול", אשר עד כה עמד אדיש נוכח מעשי הרצח הבלתי פוסקים של אנשים מישראל, "זועזע" עד היסוד למעשה קיביה שלמעשה היתה רק פעולת תגמול...ושונאי ישראל הפיקו את זממם בזה שמדינת ישראל גונתה מעל במת מועצת הביטחון של האו"ם. אנו יודעים יפה את מדת ה"יושר" המציינת את קו מדיניותן של המדינות המגנות. לא מפיהן אנו חיים, ולא מהן נלמוד יושר וצדק. אולם חובה מוטלת עלינו לברר את דרך תגובתו הנאותה לפי התורה..." ([pg. 113, note 4](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43775&pgnum=113))

Translation: "Ever since the "official" war of the Arab countries against Israel ended by ceasefire, incidents of Arab gangs infiltrating [Israel] to steal and perform armed robbery have not ceased...in Cheshvan of 5714, one of these criminal gangs brutally murdered a family in the village of Yahud. It appeared that the gangs acted in an organized manner, supported by the Arab population that lived near the border...the village that was hurt decided that they must not sit and do nothing, waiting for the next murders, and one night fiercely attacked the Arab settlement of Qibiya, which was proven that out of that place the murderous gangs came and received support from the local population...the world "at large", which until now stood idly by in the face of the never-ending murderous acts against people from Israel, was "shocked" to its core from the Qibiya Incident which in actuality, was just a reprisal operation...and the enemies of Israel realized their scheme by [seeing] Israel rebuked from the podium of the UN Security Council. We are well aware of the level of "integrity" which symbolizes the general policy of the rebuking countries, and not from their mouths do we live, and not from them will we learn integrity and justice. But it is our obligation to clarify what it the proper reaction to this, according to the Torah..."

and then proceeded to analyze the issue, and finally concluded:

> "והיוצא מכל זה, שיש מקום לפעולות תגמול ונקם נגד צוררי ישראל ופעולה כזאת היא בגדר מלחמת מצוה. וכל
> אסון ופגע שקורה לפורעים ולבעלי בריתם ולילדיהם, הם הם שערבים לזה, והם עונם ישאו. ואין שום חובה להמנע
> מפעולות תגמול מחמת חשש שיפגעו בזה חפים מפשע כי לא אנו הגורמים, כ"א הם עצמם ואנחנו נקיים.
> 'אכן לפגוע לכתחלה בכונה בילדים, כזה לא מציני אלא בחטא ע"ז. ע"כ מן הראוי לשמור עצמם מלנגע בהם. וה'
> הטוב יראה בעני עמו וצרר את צורריו ושרשם מארץ חיים. ובנו יקוים מקרא שנאמר: כל כלי יוצר לא יצלח וכל
> לשון תקום אתך למשפט תרשיעי, זאת נחלת עבדי ה' וצדקתם מאתי נאם ה'. ([pg. 139](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43775&pgnum=139))

Translate: "And what may be concluded from all of this, is that there is room for reprisal and revenge operations against the enemies of Israel, and such operations are within the limits of a commanded war (milchemet mitzvah). And any tragedy that befalls the rioters, their allies and their children, they are those who are responsible for one another, and they shall carry the weight of their sins. And there is no obligation to avoid reprisal operations for fear of hurting innocents because we are not the cause [of pain inflicted upon innocents], for they themselves [are the cause] and we are clean. Indeed, however, in the case of hurting children in the first place, we have only found this in the case of the sin of idolatry. Therefore, it is appropriate to try to be careful to not hurt them. And the good LORD will see the fallen state of His nation and will destroy the enemies and remove them from the land of life. And in us will be fulfilled the verse "No weapon formed against you shall succeed, and every tongue that contends with you at law You shall defeat. Such is the lot of the servants of the LORD, such their triumph through Me—declares the LORD.""

Comment: @Bochur613 thanks for somewhat undeserved points... A couple of days ago I found a Teshuva from Rabbi Hertzog which looked like it was on this subject, but I haven't had time yet to properly look at it and potentially add it to my answer. Hope to do that eventually.